# Does sinning on purpose and stopping salah affect person rizq in Islam?

Tags: salat, islamic-philosophy, sin

To be honest I use to pray and try not to sin and I had many pretty things in life. Now when I stopped salah and I admit i do small sins on purpose I start having problem sleeping at night and well I am not being productive or successful at all.Now I have problems every day and I feel weak

Answer (score -1):

Although Allah give rizq to believes and non-believes alike. There are 5 things a person get if he does his 5 daily prays on their fixed stated time

1) His daily bread is made easy for him;

2)he is saved from the punishment of the Qabar;

3) He will receive the record of his deeds in his right hand on the Day of Judgment;

4) He will successfully cross the bridge of Sira’at

5) He shall enter Jannah.

Point 1. might ansewer your Question.

Comment: Evidences would make this answer more useful.